# How to pass html li tag value to aspx.cs page?

Tags: asp.net, html

When i scan qr code the qr code value stored into {{scan.content}} . Now i want to get  this value of scan.content  in aspx.cs page. How to pass {{scan.content}} value to aspx.cs after scanning the qr code .

This is my code:

```
<section class="scans">
      <h2>Scans</h2>
      <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
        <li class="empty">No scans yet</li>
      </ul>
      <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
        <li id="scanvalueid"  name="scanvaluename" v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content" >{{ scan.content }}</li>

      </transition-group>
    </section>
```

---

Comment: if you want to submit the value to the server, it needs to either be within a form input element, or you can use Javascript to extract it from the DOM and send via ajax. Do you know how to submit forms in asp.net?

Comment: i get the value using this code var x = document.getElementById("scanvalueid").title; Now i want pass the value of x into aspx.cs page?

Comment: well you can easily pass it to your server using ajax (but this is of course outside the full page postback lifecycle). If you want to post back the whole page and get the value then, I repeat, the value needs to be inside a form element like an `<asp:Textbox` or an `<input runat="server"` type of element. What do you plan to do with the value when it gets to the server? If you just want to store it in the database then ajax will work nicely. If you want to use it to manipulate the rest of the page some other way then postback might be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can put runat="server" attribute in li and can access in backend.

Comment: i am using html5. Now  i get the value using this code var x = document.getElementById("scanvalueid").title; Now i want pass the value of x into aspx.cs page?